# C# Group by Timestamp produces duplicate keys

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to group a collection of Timestamp (DateTime) and I can see groupby produces duplicate keys on our production environment.

```
foreach (var price in prices.GroupBy(x => x.Timestamp))
{
    logger.LogInformation($"{price.Key.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}");
}


2021-10-01 20:54:49.661
2021-10-01 21:00:00.356
2021-10-03 21:05:03.816
2021-10-03 21:05:15.876
2021-10-03 21:05:29.140
2021-10-03 21:05:51.356
2021-10-03 21:06:04.996
2021-10-03 21:06:15.308
2021-10-03 21:06:44.648
2021-10-03 21:06:58.521
2021-10-01 20:54:49.661
2021-10-01 21:00:00.356
2021-10-03 21:05:03.816
2021-10-03 21:05:15.876
2021-10-03 21:05:29.140
2021-10-03 21:05:51.356
2021-10-03 21:06:04.996
2021-10-03 21:06:15.308
2021-10-03 21:06:44.648
2021-10-03 21:06:58.521
```

On my local machine the exact same code produces the following which is correct

```
2021-10-01 20:54:49.661
2021-10-01 21:00:00.356
2021-10-03 21:05:03.816
2021-10-03 21:05:15.876
2021-10-03 21:05:29.140
2021-10-03 21:05:51.356
2021-10-03 21:06:04.996
2021-10-03 21:06:15.308
2021-10-03 21:06:44.648
2021-10-03 21:06:58.521
```

Anyone knows the reason why that happens?

Comment: It looks like you have a precision problem. Those keys are not duplicated but when you format them you only use 2 precision scale that makes them duplicates. If you want this output you should use the same format when you are grouping them.

Comment: @Eldar Grouping happens on datetime. Output was just formatted to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your first output repeats itself halfway, then *something* in those keys are different. You don't see all details through your `ToString()` format string.

Repro:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var dateTimes = new []
{
    new DateTime(now.Ticks),
    new DateTime(now.Ticks),
    new DateTime(now.Ticks + 1),
    new DateTime(now.Ticks + 2),
    new DateTime(now.Ticks + 3),
};

var groupedDateTimes = dateTimes.GroupBy(x => x);

foreach (var grouped in groupedDateTimes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{grouped.Key.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")} (count: {grouped.Count()})");
}
```

Gives:

```
2021-11-03 09:22:57.585592 (count: 2)
2021-11-03 09:22:57.585592 (count: 1)
2021-11-03 09:22:57.585592 (count: 1)
2021-11-03 09:22:57.585592 (count: 1)
```

The keys *look* the same, but their ticks are different. If you have DateTimes with equal ticks as you claim, then perhaps your production code just calls the method twice or otherwise duplicates the data. `GroupBy()` is not broken, assume your code is.

Comment: `DateTime.Kind` wouldn't cause this - it isn't used in equality checks. I suspect it's sub-millisecond differences.

Comment: Yes that is what I suspected. I tried to group by Timestamp.Ticks but still the same result.

Comment: @Jon thanks for that correction, went by heart.

Comment: How do I overcome the sub millisecond issue?

Comment: @pantonis then read [ask] and provide a [mre] with a couple of hardcoded `DateTime` values that still trip up `GroupBy()` in the way that you observe. Changes are that in doing so you'll find the difference. We can't see your `prices` nor where they come from. Create a repro.